# Decryption: Unable to start the activity

Tags: android, encryption, android-manifest, fatal-error

I am developing an Encryption and Decryption Application. The application has 2 buttons: 1st is for Decrypt File and 2nd is for Decrypty Message.
Both buttons execute in same activity i:e DecryptActivity.java

When I press Decrypt File button, it runs smoothly, but when I press Decrypt Message button, the log cat shows error:

```
 07-24 13:09:26.732: W/dalvikvm(27183): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x419aeba8)
07-24 13:09:26.732: E/AndroidRuntime(27183): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-24 13:09:26.732: E/AndroidRuntime(27183): Process: gargdk.android.mailencryption, PID: 27183
07-24 13:09:26.732: E/AndroidRuntime(27183): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{gargdk.android.mailencryption/gargdk.android.mailencryption.DecryptActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-24 13:09:26.732: E/AndroidRuntime(27183):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
07-24 13:09:26.732: E/AndroidRuntime(27183):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
07-24 13:09:26.732: E/AndroidRuntime(27183):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
07-24 13:09:26.732: E/AndroidRuntime(27183):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
07-24 13:09:26.732: E/AndroidRuntime(27183):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
07-24 13:09:26.732: E/AndroidRuntime(27183):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
07-24 13:09:26.732: E/AndroidRuntime(27183):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
07-24 13:09:26.732: E/AndroidRuntime(27183):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-24 13:09:26.732: E/AndroidRuntime(27183):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-24 13:09:26.732: E/AndroidRuntime(27183):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
07-24 13:09:26.732: E/AndroidRuntime(27183):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
07-24 13:09:26.732: E/AndroidRuntime(27183):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-24 13:09:26.732: E/AndroidRuntime(27183): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-24 13:09:26.732: E/AndroidRuntime(27183):    at java.util.regex.Matcher.reset(Matcher.java:177)
07-24 13:09:26.732: E/AndroidRuntime(27183):    at java.util.regex.Matcher.<init>(Matcher.java:90)
07-24 13:09:26.732: E/AndroidRuntime(27183):    at java.util.regex.Pattern.matcher(Pattern.java:297)
07-24 13:09:26.732: E/AndroidRuntime(27183):    at gargdk.android.mailencryption.DecryptActivity.onCreate(DecryptActivity.java:260)
07-24 13:09:26.732: E/AndroidRuntime(27183):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
07-24 13:09:26.732: E/AndroidRuntime(27183):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
07-24 13:09:26.732: E/AndroidRuntime(27183):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
07-24 13:09:26.732: E/AndroidRuntime(27183):    ... 11 more
```

I have checked other post, but the error is not solving. Android Manifesto file already has the entry.

Android Manisfesto file:

```
 <activity
        android:name="gargdk.android.mailencryption.DecryptActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_decrypt"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|keyboard">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="gargdk.android.mailencryption.intent.DECRYPT" />
            <action android:name="gargdk.android.mailencryption.intent.DECRYPT_FILE" />
            <action android:name="gargdk.android.mailencryption.intent.DECRYPT_AND_RETURN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <data android:mimeType="*/*"/>
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
```

The Code of DecryptActivity.java

```
 256   if (mSource.getCurrentView().getId() == R.id.sourceMessage &&
 257       mMessage.getText().length() == 0) {
 258       ClipboardManager clip = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
 259       String data = "";
 260       Matcher matcher = Apg.PGP_MESSAGE.matcher(clip.getText());
 261       if (!matcher.matches()) {
 262           matcher = Apg.PGP_SIGNED_MESSAGE.matcher(clip.getText());
 263       }
 264       if (matcher.matches()) {
 265           data = matcher.group(1);
 266           mMessage.setText(data);
 267           Toast.makeText(this, R.string.usingClipboardContent,   
267 Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
268       }
269    }
```

Comment: u post ur code ??code as well as xml

Comment: check what is null in `DecryptActivity.onCreate(DecryptActivity.java:260)`

Comment: What is there at line number 177?

Comment: @blackbelt at 260: Matcher matcher = Apg.PGP_MESSAGE.matcher(clip.getText());

Comment: @Aniruddha at line 176 } catch (IOException e) {
          177      // ignore, then
          178  }

Comment: `clip.getText()` can return null

Comment: @adcomI have added the xml and java file code (though it is not full)

Comment: @blackbelt so whats the solution. The eclipse shows me 2 quick fixes, but they are not working.

Comment: You can check to see if the clipboard has text with clip.hasText()

Comment: @raz Nope, the problem is still there. When I change, it create an other error: The method matcher(CharSequence) in the type Pattern is not applicable for the arguments (boolean) (when I convert from clip.getText() to clip.hasText()).

Comment: clip.hasText() only checks to see if there is text to be received with clip.getText().  You need to do something like:  if(clip.hasText()) { matcher = Apg.PGP_MESSAGE.matcher(clip.getText()); etc }  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/ClipboardManager.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `clip.getText()` can return `null` if there is no text in the clipboard.  To avoid a null pointer here, call `clip.hasText()` to see if there is some text in the clipboard.  [Android docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/ClipboardManager.html)

For Example:

```
if(clip.hasText()) {
    // Do stuff with clip
}
```